# JQuery to change icon in HTML

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i>
```

which just shows an icon, how can i change this class to `fa fa-toggle-off` using jQuery?

I also want to be able to change it back to `on`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)**

```
$('.fa').toggleClass('fa-toggle-on fa-toggle-off');
```

---

```js
$('.fa').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-toggle-on fa-toggle-off');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i>
```

Comment: @charlie : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass):

```
$('i').toggleClass('fa-toggle-on fa-toggle-off');
```